# Do I need to use 'the' in this case?: the implications of study findings

Tags: articles

I hope to clarify that I used 'the' in a right place in the following sentence.

'The findings of this study'
'The implicatinos of study findings'

Since 'findings' and 'implications' are limited by 'of the study' and 'of study findings', I think that I need to use 'the'. Am I correct? Could you review the following sentence?:

Since the PSED data sampled only nascent entrepreneurs in the U.S., the findings of this study would not be applicable to other countries. Therefore, the implications of study findings are limited to the U.S. context.

Comment: Is the implicatino another particle they're spending billions trying to prove the existence of?

Answer (score 1):

It would be possible without *the*, but much more natural with *the*. (Without it, it would suggest that you are thinking of the findings as a general set, from which you are going to select some for consideration).

I would also replace *study findings* by *the findings* (or *the study findings* if you must, but I find that awkward). The findings have already been introduced, so take *the* when mentioned again.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't see a need for either here. I'd hope that the reader hasn't forgot the study about which they're reading, half a sentence later!

How about:

> Since the PSED data sampled only nascent entrepreneurs in the U.S.,
>   the findings of this study would not be applicable to other countries.
>   The implications are therefore limited to the US context.

To me, lessening the repetition allows the paragraph to scan more easily.